# Bitly links in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I use `Bitly` Wordpress plugin and function `wp_get_shortlink()`. On simple posts it works fine, but on custom post types the links are not converted and when I share on twitter, my share link is something like `domain/?p=43432`.

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: You should ask authors of the plugin. It is probably something which they forgot to implement

Comment: Can you give us a link to the plugin that you're using?

Comment: ReLeaf, https://vip.wordpress.com/plugins/bitly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That VIP plugin doesn't support `post_type` values beyond "post" by default, but this handy function should solve it for you:

```
/**
 * Add Bitly to CPT's
 */
function my_add_bitly_cpts( $post_types ) {
    $post_types[] = 'my_custom_post_type_name';
    return $post_types;
}
add_filter( 'bitly_post_types' , 'my_add_bitly_cpts' );
```